# Tensorflow Split Using Feed Dict Input Dimension

Tags: python, nlp, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, word-embedding

I'm trying to tf.split a tensor based on the dimension of an input fed in using feed_dict (dimension of input changes with each batch). Currently I keep getting an error saying that a tensor cannot be split with a "Dimension". Is there a way to get the value of the dimension and split using it?

Thanks!

```
input_d = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, None], name="input_d")

# toy feed dict
feed = {
    input_d: [[20,30,40,50,60],[2,3,4,5,-1]] # document
}

W_embeddings = tf.get_variable(shape=[vocab_size, embedding_dim], \
                  initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(-0.01, 0.01),\
                  name="W_embeddings")  
document_embedding = tf.gather(W_embeddings, input_d)

timesteps_d = document_embedding.get_shape()[1]
doc_input = tf.split(1, timesteps_d, document_embedding)
```

Comment: What is the error message? Can you print out the value of `seq_lens` an `document_embedding`?

Comment: `TypeError: Expected int for argument 'num_split' not Dimension(None).`

Comment: how about `get_shape().shape[1]`?

Answer (score 0):

`tf.split` takes a python integer for the `num_split` argument. However, `document_embedding.get_shape()` returns a `TensorShape`, and `document_embedding.get_shape()[1]` gives a `Dimension` instance, hence you get an error says "can't split with a Dimension".

Try `timestep_ds = document_embedding.get_shape().as_list()[1]`, this statement should give you a python integer.

Here are some relevant documentations for [tf.split](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#split) and [tf.Tensor.get_shape](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/framework.html#Tensor)